# Execute SSIS package is not working with SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, winscp

I post this question to the other forums too but still cannot find any solution.
I create SSIS package to send file to SFTP server. It works fine when I execute the package with in the SSIS.
But when I tried to run via SQL agent it keeps on running without sending the file until I stops the job by force.
I add the proxy account too but no solution.
**My script to run the package is**

```
option batch on 
option confirm off 
open sftp://UserName:Password@SFTP server Name :22001 -timeout=240
cd ToAA
option transfer binary 
put C:\test29022016.csv
mget *.csv
Exit WinSCP 
close
exit
```

*Kindly help to solve this issue*

Attached find the SSIS package details:
[image]

SQL server credentials:
[image]

SQL Process Keeps on Running:
[image]

SQL Job:
[image]

SQL [image]Credentials:

Comment: The SQL Agent accontu has privileges to do that

Comment: Does it work when you login as the same account as the SQL Agent and run the package in SSIS?

Comment: If the answer by @TabAlleman does not help, make sure you enable logging (using `/log=c:\path\to\winscp.log` command-line switch) and show us the log.

Comment: Hi I've tried all option but no result.

Comment: What options did you try? Where's the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around and I am using windows task scheduler with the help of batch file to run SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between you running the package manually, and the SQL Agent running it as a job, is the account that is running the package.   In the first case it is your account, and in the second case, it is the SQL Agent's account.

So if it works in the first case, and not the other, then the problem is that the SQL Agent lacks some permission that you have.

Have your network/security administrator give the SQL Agent **all** the same permissions you have and it will work.

To find out exactly what permission is missing, try logging into your computer as the SQL Agent's account, and run the package in Visual Studio, and see what error message occurs.

Comment: Hi All,
Just to give you an update SQL Agent and windows account both are running as same administrator account.